# percentage unite (problem solving for primary school)

Tags: percentages

I am trying to come up with an interesting problem to show my students how the percentage units work. In their book I can only find the problems for ex: "the interesting rate has risen from 2% to 3%. How big is the increase a) in percentage unites b) in percent." What do you think of a problem like this: "Sam's wages has risen for 3,4% and Maria's wages has risen for 4,5%. How much less has Sam's wages risen compared to Marias rise? (calculate it in percentage unites and in percent)". Apart from the question if this problem is well defined, I also want to ask you, guys, if you have a more interesting problem where one can see better when and why we use the percentage units and when the percentage. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think ["percentage point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point) would be a more common term than "percentage unite".

Comment: Oh, yes! I am sorry. I am not so familiar at using this terminology in English.

Comment: Ask your students to solve differential equations.

Comment: Also, it is _interest_ rate (not _interesting_).

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in the future, questions like yours here may be better suited for the [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) SE site. Nonetheless, before possibly posting any questions there, please first read their [Help Center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help) as to what sorts of questions are appropriate (and those which are not), as well as going through at least a few of their questions, especially those with tags applicable to what you're asking about, to get a better feel for what is, and is not, accepted there.